# WIX and Certificates in IIS

Tags: wix, wix3

I am trying to setup my install to have my site configured with its certificate using WIX.

I can view the certificate in IIS and have access to the .cer file.  That is about all I know about certificates, so please dumb down any answers.  (ie I have no idea what my "BinaryKey" is).

The certificate is already installed on the machine.  Ideally I would like to just have a way in wix to configure which installed certificate to use.  If anyone knows how to do that please post it here!

If that can't be done, then I would love a good example of how to install (and maybe uninstall) a certificate.

Thanks for any and all answers.

Vaccano

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okaaay, so no one big on the WIX Certificates scene.

Here is what I did that ended up working:

Under my website:

```
<iis:Certificate Id="MyCert" Name="MyCertName" StoreName="root"
StoreLocation="localMachine" BinaryKey="Certificate.Binary" />
```

Under Project:

```
<Binary Id="Certificate.Binary" SourceFile="$(var.CertificatePath)" />
```

`$(var.CertificatePath)` is a setup to point to my .cer file.

Comment: As I remember this causes the certificate to be reinstalled on every run of the installer.  (Not really what I wanted.)  Though when setting an service up in IIS up manually you can select already installed certificates.  There is no way to do this in WIX.