# How to create an Installer for multiple applications

Tags: installation

My problem is the following:
I have multiple applications that I want pack in one installer so when the user runs it, they will be installed automatically instead of installing or copying each single application.
I have a program that's already a setup file (.exe) and two .exe files which can be executed manually and do not need an installation. So what I want is:
Build an installer so when the user opens it - the .exe file of the setup program gets installed and the other applications which dont need to be installed will be copied somewhere in a path.
Whats the best solution?

Comment: You better use installBuilders like http://installbuilder.bitrock.com

Comment: I tried Inno Setup now but how to include the setup file into it to be run automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a packaging programs to create an installation package, such as:
AdvancedInstaller
InstallShield
InstallAnyware

The first two of them have a freeware version. Maybe you can see if the required features are available in the freeware version.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest **Advanced Installer** (allows easy chaining of installs) if you have no significant deployment experience. Otherwise I would suggest **Wix** and its "**Burn**" feature (ability to chain installers in sequence). Please read the following answers for context:

- **[What installation product to use? InstallShield, WiX, Wise, Advanced Installer, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544292/what-installation-product-to-use-installshield-wix-wise-advanced-installer/1546941#1546941)**
- [Windows Installer and the creation of WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060281/windows-installer-and-the-creation-of-wix/12101548#12101548)
- [Wix to Install multiple Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542656/wix-to-install-multiple-applications/1546916#1546916)
- [Read this if you want to get going with Wix quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26917214/add-remove-programs-show-increased-size-after-each-reinstall-of-my-msi-product/26946138#26946138)